# Why bcrypt compare return false for the same password and hash on different server?

Tags: node.js, encryption, bcrypt

I have an express application that generates a hash using bcrypt and I have a login page that retrieves that hash and compares it with the entered password.

## **Problem:**

I have uploaded my code and my **database** and now I can't login. If I generate my password on my server then I can login but I cannot use my local machine hashes. If I bring the hash generated on my server to my local machine then I can't login in my local environment. I have also generated hash online and replaced my hash password and again I can't login. It seems the password must be generated on the same machine otherwise it won't work

Can someone explain what's happening? Also, how can I fix this?

Comment: Could you post the `bcrypt hashing` code here. And also, the `cost` provided for both `bcrypt` methods, is it same or different? And are both library versions are same( wrt to default salt cost)